# Incomprehensible unexpected token error in do...while loop

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, do-loops

It's perhaps the first time I use a `do...while` loop. I can't figure out what's wrong with it:

```
const randomLetter
do {  
  randomLetter = String.fromCharCode(97 + 26 * Math.random() | 0)
} while (state.lettersFound.includes(randomLetter))
```

At line `do {` I'm getting some `unexpected token` syntax error. Why?

Comment: You can't assign to a const.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:vue.js]?

Comment: @tkausl gosh that was it, thanks a lot. My attention was laser-focused on the `do {` since that's what the compiler was so misleadingly pointing to

Comment: @drake035 It says that the `do` is unexpected because it first expects an assignment to `const randomLetter`, which you didn't provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [syntax for declaring a constant](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations) is:

`const` *Identifier* `=` *Initializer*

The parser is expecting to see an equals sign `=` after the identifier (`randomLetter`), but instead it unexpectedly sees the keyword `do`.

So, the error message and the error location is correct: the unexpected token is the keyword `do` and the error occurs at the token `do`.

Note: depending on the parser, the error message is more or less helpful, e.g. I get this in [Node.js 13.1.0](https://nodejs.org/) / [V8 7.8](https://v8.dev/):

```
Thrown:
const randomLetter
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
```

Note: this is not really about [do-loops](/questions/tagged/do-loops): *anything* that is not an equals sign `=` would trigger a similar syntax error.

Note: [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js) *cannot possibly* have anything to do with this, since it is clearly a syntax / parse error and ECMAScript (like almost all languages and certainly all mainstream languages) does not allow libraries to change the fundamental syntax of the language.